# How to stop/pause a SPECIFIC force in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

### Problem

I have a directed graph. It has 3 forces:

- Centering force
- Many-body force
- Link force

I want to temporarily disable the `centering` force. I am not asking for how to disable the *whole* force layout, only one specific force.

### What I tried

I have looked extensively through the documentation on `d3.forceSimulation` and `force` function but nowhere does it mention how to pause a force.
I have tried to delete then reset the force by something like this:

```
this.simulation.force("center", null);
```

in `dragstart` then

```
this.simulation.force("center", oldCenterForce)
```

in `dragend`. The problem is that when drag ends, the nodes instantly jump back to the center, there is no smooth transition.

I have also tried giving a custom `force` function that checks if `this.isDragging`. If it is dragging, then I return a dumb function `(alpha) => {}`, if not then I return `d3.forceCenter(...)` but it complains about a missing `node` array. I tried doing `.bind(this.simulation)` before calling the function, but still doesn't work.

### Code

The part where I create the force simulation and store it in `this.simulation`

```
  createForceSimulation = (nodeData: G.Node[], edgeData: G.Link[]) => {
     d3.forceSimulation(nodeData)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(edgeData).id((d: any) => d.id))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(this.props.width / 2, this.props.height / 2))
      .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(this.circleSize * 2))
      .velocityDecay(this.simulationVelocityDecay)
  }
```

The part where I handle dragging a node:

```
  drag = simulation => {
    const dragStarted = d => {
      if (!d3.event.active) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0.7).restart()
      }
      d.fx = d.x
      d.fy = d.y
    }

    const dragged = d => {
      d.fx = d3.event.x
      d.fy = d3.event.y
    }

    const dragEnded = d => {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0)
      d.fx = null
      d.fy = null
    }

    return d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", dragStarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragEnded)
  }
```

## Summary

Expected: force to stop momentarily
Actual: force doesn't stop or crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom center force with a strength parameter.

```
.force("center", myCenterForce(this.props.width / 2, this.props.height / 2))
```

In drag functions call

```
simulation.force("center").strength(0);

simulation.force("center").strength(1.0);
```

Or you can animate/interpolate the strength in the tick function.

```
var dragNode = null;

  drag = simulation => {
    const dragStarted = function (d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0.7).restart()
      }
      dragNode = null;
      d.fx = d.x
      d.fy = d.y
    }

    const dragged = function (d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x
      d.fy = d3.event.y
    }

    const dragEnded = function (d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      dragNode = this;
      d3.select(this).attr("data-strength", 0)
          .transition().duration(2000)
          .attr("data-strength", 1.0)
          .on("end", function () { dragNode = null; } );
      d.fx = null
      d.fy = null
    }

    return d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", dragStarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragEnded)
  }

function tick() {
    if (dragNode)
        simulation.force("center")
            .strength(d3.select(dragNode).attr("data-strength"));

    // update nodes
}
```

Custom force

```
function myCenterForce(x, y) {
  var nodes;
  var strength = 1.0;

  if (x == null) x = 0;
  if (y == null) y = 0;

  function force() {
    var i,
        n = nodes.length,
        node,
        sx = 0,
        sy = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      node = nodes[i], sx += node.x, sy += node.y;
    }

    for (sx = sx / n - x, sy = sy / n - y, i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      node = nodes[i], node.x -= strength * sx, node.y -= strength * sy;
    }
  }

  force.initialize = function(_) {
    nodes = _;
  };

  force.x = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (x = +_, force) : x;
  };

  force.y = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (y = +_, force) : y;
  };

  force.strength = function(_) {
    return arguments.length ? (strength = +_, force) : strength;
  };

  return force;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to use the one with `data-strength` because I couldn't differentiate between the `this` of `drag` and the this of the react class this whole simulation is happening inside. What I ended up doing is setting `strength(0)` when drag starts then `strength(0.1)` when it ends. Setting it to `1` makes the nodes instantly jump back to the center, while `0.1` makes it a smooth transition. This is a hacky way of doing but does its job nevertheless so thank you for that!

Comment: the animated version uses `function` so `this` is the DOM node.